# How to generate dynamic multi-dimensional list or array and insert data accordingly based on a dynamic SQL Server table in c#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, insert, dynamic-arrays

I want to create a dynamic 2-dimensional array (or any other structure) based on a dynamic database table in C# or T-SQL, which means the data source (which is a database table) is dynamic too.

EDIT:

Table structure:

[image]

For example:

If `User1` meets the condition of `Admin` and `Group1`, it will be inserted into `(Admin, Group1)`. And the users are constantly added in with different user type and group. So, every cellular can have as many as users.

And the problem is I don't know how many user types and groups there are, because **new user types and new groups** are added constantly too.

[image]

For now, I think I need to parse every data to find if it meets the existing conditions. If yes, insert it into the specific condition; if not, create a new condition and insert data into it.

But I don't have any idea about how to implement it? Do you have any ideas or algorithms?

Thanks very much for any suggestion or information.

Comment: dynamically allocate a pointer sized by colsize*rowsize?

Comment: For me the question is not clear at all.

Comment: new columns and rows will be inserted with time

Comment: @charlessun why do you really want to create new columns in db dynamically from time to time? I think there can be better solution to your problem, may be u want to get the db design right?

Comment: @nawfal the table columns are not dynamically added. please see my edit. I hope it's more clear.

Comment: @Jim I've modified the post

Comment: @charlessun if columns too depend on dynamic values from the db, then it will be better to not auto-refresh yourself. Build a static mechanism with values at the time of loading, and let user refresh manually (upon which you will repopulate the gridview or whatever that is). Otherwise you will have to manually do it yourself as u state towards the last in your question.

Comment: If you can put reasonable bounds on one or the other (cols or rows) then you could allocate a certain size and then realloc as the unbounded parameter (cols, for example) grows.  It's tougher if both can grow without bounded without majorly reworking the data from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this statically with Tuple, but not dynamically. I think I should re-fresh my tuple list periodically. But at least, it works now!

Any suggestions are welcome! Thanks!